# How can I Export user reviews from Android Play

Tags: android, google-play, user-feedback

I'd like to export the full text and details of user reviews on `Google Play`. The export button on the statistics page allows to export device and rating but it does not export the text.

I'd like to be able to search the text for things like `"doesn't install"` or text that indicates a lack of basic application functionality so that I can blacklist those devices or work to fix them in future versions...

Answer (score 1):

You can export ratings and reviews from the Developer Console and analyze trends in bulk to understand your user feedback better. Reports are generated daily, accumulated in monthly CSV files, and stored in a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

> **Field   | Format**
>  Reviewer Language    | String - ISO 639-1 two letter
>   abbreviation
>  Device   | String
>  Review Submit Date and Time    |
>   ISO_8601 including time, UTC timezone
>  Star Rating | int32 (between
>   1 and 5)
>  Review Title | String, in the reviewer's local language
>   (stripping newlines)
>  Review Text  | String, in the reviewer's local
>   language (stripping newlines)

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138230#export_ratings_and_reviews

Answer (score 1):

I know this questions is two years old and this option may not have been available at the time of asking, but if you're looking to export ratings/reviews, there's an option in the ReviewsPlace of the Developer Console to download ratings/reviews to a CSV. It's located at the top right of the page, just under the header.

Comment: Yeah. At the time there was nothing. Google has done a lot for devs since.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to pull the "Play store" and "App store" reviews. checkout the reference links below,

Direct support (Google): 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870

3rd party support:
https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-get-all-reviews-of-an-app-on-Google-Play-Store-Is-there-any-API